# Setting showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO hides also horizontal indicator in iOS7

Tags: uiscrollview, ios7, scrollbar

When I set the vertical scrollbar indicator to NO, it also hides the horizontal scroll bar in iOS7

scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO; -> hides also horizontal bar as wel